# Intersection of a line with an n-dimensional axis aligned box, a paradox?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have a n-dimensional box whose min is $(1,1,...1)$ and max is $(3,3,...,3)$. I need to find the intersection of a line from the origin $O$ to a point $P$ that is either on or within this box with one of the box faces that is closest to the origin. If the axis are $x_1, x_2, ..x_n$ then we have the planes $x_1x_2, x_1x_3...x_(n-1)x_n$ whose count is  $n*(n-1)/2$.

Each of these planes correspond to the box faces and have all their coordinate values as 1 except for any 2 of them which can vary. for example the plane $x_ix_j$ contains the points whose coordinates are all 1 except for the coordinates $x_i,x_j$.

Suppose $n=5$ and $P=(2,3,1,1,3)$. If the line $OP$ intersects one of the 10 planes, then the point of intersection should have all coordinates as 1 except for any 2 of them. But i cannot find any scalar value $t$ such that $tP$ results in all 1s except for any 2 coordinates. This implies that the point does not intersect any of the planes. Is this correct?

But the point clearly lies on or within the 5-box. So it should intersect one of the 10 bounding planes. Can anyone explain what i am missing here? Seems to be a paradox.

Also can anyone suggest or point to me any algorithm for finding this point of intersection and the plane that it intersect with? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you fixing all but two of the coordinates? That only gives you a $2$-dimensional plane in $n$ dimensions. You should be fixing only one of the coordinates to obtain an $(n-1)$-dimensional hyperplane.

Comment: if i have a n-box, then wouldnt the n*(n-1)/2 2-D planes form the box faces? In 3D the 2D planes $x_1x_2, x_1x_3, x_2x_3$ are the box faces at the $O$. If I translate the $O$ to $(1,1,1)$ all but 2 of the coordinates are fixed for all the planes. Extrapolating to higher dimensions we have $n(n-1)/2$ 2D planes at $O$ which can then be translated to $1$. i could be wrong in assuming that these are the only box faces closest to the $O$?

Comment: another question is are these planes enough to find the point of intersection? $OP$ should intersect atleast one of them?

Comment: It is misleading to "extrapolate" from just one data point. If you have a 1-box (i.e. an interval), its boundary consists of its endpoints, which are 0-dimensional. If you have a 2-box, its boundary consists of 1-dimensional edges. If you have a 3-box, its boundary consists of 2-dimensional faces. Now you can see the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the boxIntersection function of 
http://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/intersectors/intersectors.htm
It works in arbitrary dimensions.

I think your issue is with the plane normal vectors, they should be zero in all dimensions except one.